# Is there a place for 1 to 1 coaching on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As I'm a newbie, I'm kinda stucked in the logic and/or syntax of RoR at times - and so am wondering if any of y'all know a website where I can just schedule training sessions as and when I need it with tuition paid on an hourly basis?

I know it's not code related question, but searching on google didn't really help me much in finding reliable tutors (with proper credentials).
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! This sort of question is off-topic for SO. But, in the spirit of helping you get off the ground, I have seen [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io/) mentioned before. I have never used it. I'm not affiliated with it. I have been recommended to join as a mentor, but haven't gotten to it yet. Good luck!

Comment: Sure thing. BTW, in full disclosure, I did just sign up as a mentor. So, I suppose I do have some kind of affiliation now.

Comment: Sure thing, just pinpoint me as to how I can find cha' there. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Welp, I guess it takes 1-2 weeks for them to approve me. But, I have the same user name there as here - jvillian